Why does the concurrent-sweep phase in CMS work well while application threads are running?
I’ve learned about the CMS garbage collector, but I’m having trouble understanding how the concurrent-sweep phase works. If an object is marked as garbage during the remark phase and then later referenced during the concurrent-sweep phase, should CMS still collect that object?
I know there are several phases during the CMS concurrent cycle. I understand that the phases before the concurrent-sweep are responsible for determining all unreferenced objects. Is it possible for unreachable objects to become reachable again during this concurrent-sweep process?

A garbage collector never marks objects as garbage. A garbage collector traverses the graph of reachable objects, marking them as “not garbage” in the process. For an approach enabling concurrent processing, see Tri-color marking

I’ve got it now. After reading some material about tri-color marking, I realize that garbage cannot be referenced again. Thanks for your help! @Holger
